# jQueryUI. Why is the interface so big?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm writing some extension for chrome based browsers.

I'm using JSTree jQuery plugin.
jQuery UI also.

My general question is:
Why are the fonts so big? 
[image: My extension]

I want see fonts like in [demo from jQueryUI Themes Builder](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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):
[image: Theme buider show theme witout problems]

What do I need to do to fix that?

**SOLUTION:**
In HTML overide .ui-widget class:

```
font-size:12px;
```

using ***style*** html tag. 
Or do the same in your custom CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default font size in the themeroller on the jquery UI site under the "Font Settings" option.

Comment: I downloaded default theme without any changes.

Comment: You can override the default size by using `.ui-widget{font-size:12px;}`

Comment: you can either attach it to the div where you want font to be smaller (in your css file) or at the top of the page in `<style></style>` tags